# How to *quickly* reboot an unresponsive aws ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Typical workflow with an unresponsive host is to look at the logs, see it's unresponsive, try to reboot (that never works) then hit "stop" and go for coffee because it takes for ever to kill it.

Is there another workflow to quickly reboot an unresponsive instance that doesn't involve whatever AWS is doing to make things slow in the background?

Comment: What do you mean by 'that never works' after a reboot? You're not able to login to the instance? Is it happening with all of you instances or with only one or a specific group of instances?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "unresponsive host" but the answer probably includes an auto-healing ASG so the machine will be replaced before you even notice it's not responding.

Comment: @MunavirChavody Yes, I am not able to log in. These are specific instances I am using as a human for dev use. Likely not watching memory and the host becomes unreachable. Just looking for a faster reboot.

Comment: Had another issue today, pretty sure no memory issues, just host becomes unreachable. Stop/Start takes forever. Would pay for faster reboot times.